# Trim HTML string up to certain limit in java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Given an HTML string such as this :

```
<p><strong id="faq_q1">Q. What is the basic difference between Bachelor of Technology and Bachelor of Engineering?</strong></p>
```

How can I modify the string so that only first n characters from clean text are returned in same HTML format? Also how to avoid intra word breakgage?

For eg: for n=20, the above string should get transformed to

```
<p><strong id="faq_q1">Q. What is the basic </strong></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Jsoup (question tagged jsoup) something like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<p><strong id=\"faq_q1\">Q. What is the basic difference between Bachelor of Technology and "
            + "Bachelor of Engineering?</strong></p>";

    //get the p tag and strong tag and content
    Element paragraph = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html).selectFirst("p");
    Element strong = paragraph.selectFirst("p strong");
    String content = strong.text();

    // use regex to get the first 20 chars while maintaining word boundaries
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G\\s*(.{1,20})(?=\\s|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    m.find();

    // replace the text of strong element with the first 20 chars of original content
    strong.text(m.group(1));

    System.out.println(paragraph);
}
```

Comment: Great! This does work for the above string, although I was hoping for a non regex solution - you see the HTML strings I am dealing with are of different formats. Any help with that?